# How to get the result from API not only the response code

Tags: python-3.x, httpresponse

I am trying to get the result of foreign currency  exchange rate but on sending a Get request to the API "https://data.fixer.io/api/".." instead of getting a result, I am getting a response code 200  but no exchange rates are there

```
def main():
    res=requests.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest? access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY& base = INR& symbols = USD")
    if res.status_code!=200:
        raise Exception("Error : APIdidn't work")
    print(res)
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1559223544,
  "base":"INR",
  "rates":{
    "USD":0.014,

  }
}
```

Actual result :

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: try `print(res.json())`

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace it gave the expected Json response

Comment: FWIW, you could have found the answer on the very first page of python-requests doc: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

To use the data that you're pulling from the API - you need to convert it to readable json. DeepSpace is correct - you need to use `res.json()`

Append the data to a variable if you want to iterate through it or utilize it further.

`data = res.json()`